# A javascript library fails to load with requirejs

Tags: requirejs

Let me clear the context first. I have bought an admin panel template from themeforest and stuck on implementing that with requirejs. The seller does not provide support for implementation.

The theme requires the following JS file, in order to run:

https://altair_html.tzdthemes.com/assets/js/common.js

I have created a fiddle, where I have included the file and defined that with requirejs. But a function (moment) is not being defined. I dont know where I am doing wrong.

Check the fiddle here:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'common': 'https://altair_html.tzdthemes.com/assets/js/common'
    }
});

require(['common'], function (common) {
   console.log(moment);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tareksiddiki/q5kumwvg/

But the moment function loads when we load the external javascript (https://altair_html.tzdthemes.com/assets/js/common.js) within the `<script>` tag in old school way.

Comment: I've been reading requirejs docs and I think the problem is that your common.js loads modules on its own, which is something that requirejs should do. If you wanna use requirejs, maybe you should rethink a bit your approach, and have jquery and moment be required, separately, by requirejs (instead of loading a big common.js file that includes them all).

Comment: I just can't give up on this common.js file, because the whole template depends on it. I agree that loading this huge file with requirejs is definitely a bad idea. But giving up should not be the solution. I will move on to another template, but I want to know why exactly the issue is occurring.

Comment: It's probable that requirejs blocks all other requests (via events, for instance) thus preventing that your common.js file loads the moment library.